# Is there a Reference Layer in the World Imagery Basemap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online-basemaps, world-imagery

How do I turn on the reference layer in the World Imagery Basemap?

It is not located on the Table of Contents.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to select the World Imagery with labels. The [World Imagery page](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9) at ArcGIS.com has a reference indicating:

> *There are three ready to use web maps that use the World Imagery service as their basemap, Imagery, in which both reference layers are
>   turned off, Imagery with Labels, which has World Boundaries and Places
>   turned on but World Transportation turned off, and Imagery with Labels
>   and Transportation, which has both reference layers turned on.*